# Using Google Calendar API from Google Sites

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-sites

I have a website created by sites.google.com.
Using Embed option, I would like to use Google Calendar API to display calendar events (we have specific format requirements that the default Calendar option does not provide).
When I try my javascript code from localhost:8000, I am able to display the calendar events.
However, when I put the code (basically identical to the javascript quickstart https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) in my website in sites.google.com, I get an error "Not a valid origin for the client: https://1737011456-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com has not been registered".
I tried to add googleusercontent.com as allowed origin, but I get "Invalid Origin: uses a forbidden domain" error.

How can I use Google Calendar API on Google Sites?

Comment: what happens if you add  https://1737011456-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com as a JavaScript origin?

Comment: The error says "Invalid Origin: uses a forbidden domain". Plus, the subdomain changes every time and we can't use a wild card (*) so that's pretty much the only way I can use it

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go against Apps Script. Firefox blocks the embedded website by default and there were other complications I wasn't too happy about.

This was the alternative approach I found online. Replace the CALENDAR_ID and API_KEY and you'll get the public events from the given calendar if you have the api key to access it:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/CALENDAR_ID/events?key=API_KEY